# Office 365 Outlook Add-in Auth error on deployment

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

I have an Outlook 365 add-in which was working. It also works in development. But when I deploy it (I upload the manifest and deploy to an Azure site). It doesn't work I just get a grey-out place holder. I suspect some kind of authentication issue as I can see this error (see below) in Chrome tools.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2018-01-14T15:33:21"
    }
  }
}
```

It also would make sense as I spent a lot of time in the Azure AD trying to get another app to work. I suspect I've deleted something but even when I deploy a fresh app I get the same problem.

Comment: What kind off add-in is that? Custom made? What authentication token are you sending? Have you re-logged-in after deployment?

Comment: It's an Outlook add-in, I'm a developer it's one I've made myself, I have relogged in. I suspect I deleted something because when I go to the AD in Azure and then go my personal apps the app registration is gone but I've added a new app and that isn't working

Comment: You should check how your add-in itself is trying to authenticate. Can you inspect that?

Comment: How can I check

Answer (score 0):

If you have re-logged in then you need to start inspecting what your extensions/addon is doing - mainly, how it is trying to authenticate. It is most likely that it is passing an incorrect authentication token.

To inspect we have two ways:

- client side, using chrome dev tools. With dev tools you can use these steps. In the extension bar in chrome, press: inspect pop-up > this will open the dev tools > then press network tab > login or do some activities with your extension > observe the network tab > press on any specific request issued by your extension > check the request it has made:

[image]

- server side - inspecting the logs. To see Azure AD use this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-log-audit

Comment: If the problem is the initial log that the Add-In makes to get things like the email properties etc, which log is the most appropriate. I've tried looking at these two in the Azure AD logs - Sign-ins and Audit Logs. Even though I set them up over two hours ago nothing is showing up.

Comment: Have your tried the chrome dev tools approach (or the same thing with different browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing I see in Chrome that makes the most sense is a call to the graph API, which produces the JSON error in the original post.